# DRAM Rank-Level Allocations

Tags: memory, computer-architecture, dram, physical-design

I want to do allocations on a specific `DRAM` *rank*. The smallest allocation unit in an *OS* such as `Linux` is at the **page size granularity**, which is typically *4KB*. So I need to be able to place at least a complete page in a `DRAM` *rank*.

But based on [DRAMDig Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.02354.pdf)<sup>1</sup> and page *20* of [Datasheet, volume 1 (M- and H-processor lines)](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getcontent/328901) (i.e., my processor chipset family), my `Haswell` processor uses *channel interleaving* when *DIMM*s are placed in slots belonging to different channels (my system has two *DIMM*, a `4GB` and a `8GB`). In other words, successive `64-byte` (which is, unfortunately, less than `4KB`) allocations are mapped to **different channels** and, consequently, **different ranks** (e.g., *physical address* `0` is mapped to *rank 0* of *DIMM 0* which is located at *channel 0*, while *physical address* `64` is mapped to *rank 0* of *DIMM1* which is located at *channel 1*), for **performance** reasons. My questions are:

**1)** Is it possible to set the channel interleaving bit at a **higher order index** so as to make `4KB` *single-rank* allocations possible?

**2)** Otherwise, is it possible to **disable** channel interleaving purely **in software**?

**3)** Otherwise, is **placing** both *DIMMs* in the **same-channel slots** the only remaining approach? This is equivalent to the following statement: *channel interleaving does not allow single rank allocations.*

Any help, suggestions and guesses are appreciated. I am stuck and the documentations are rather vague.

---

<sup>1</sup> **Table 2** on **page 5** shows *mapping functions* (from **physical addresses** to **DRAM components**). In all *dual-channel* configurations, a **low-order bit** (a bit in the range `[6-8]`) is used as the *channel interleave bit* while it should be at least **bit 12** to make `4KB` **single-rank allocations** possible.

Comment: Check your BIOS settings. Otherwise ,no.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce performance this way?

Comment: The main reason is power reduction. `DRAM` power modes are applied at *rank* level. Therefore, I want to manage allocations at this level. But, in *multi-channel configurations* this seems **not** to work. Because the allocations are **disributed** between ranks at a **fine** granularity.

Answer (score 1):

Haswell supports approx 32 GB if memory serves.

And the traditional wisdom is, that channel interleaving only happens if the DIMM modules are identical, channel to channel (mirror style). If the DIMMs are not identical, the BIOS won't engage interleaving.

If you have just two DIMMs, 1x 4GB + 1x 8GB = 12 GB total, your RAM controller is likely running them in consecutive / concatenated mode. (The effect of double RAM bandwidth does not happen.) Some BIOSes report interleaved mode somewhere in the POST screen - in your BIOS, try suppressing quick POST, disable graphical bitmap logo / welcome screen, some BIOSes allow you to add an extra delay after POST - to read the POST messages. PauseBreak also tends to work during POST. To know for sure if your BIOS reports interleaving or not, you'd have to plug in two identical DIMM modules and try to find the message in the POST screens.

If your memory controller does in fact run in interleaved mode, you probably should not try to change this from your running OS, even if the hardware would allow you to (which it likely won't allow, as these chipset config registers tend to be locked against modification by the BIOS at the end of POST, irreversibly to the OS).

Guess what would happen if your BIOS and OS were all started up with the RAM interleaved, and you'd remove the interleaving. I mean the effect would be fun to think about - like an office shredder. On the computer screen it wouldn't actually be all that interesting, probably. The OS would likely just freeze hard. Unless the GPU framebuffer would also get shredded, which could yield some interesting visual effect after all...

If you'd like to access just one DIMM at a time, and they're interleaved, and you know the "stride" of the interleaving, how about this: The interleaving "stride" length is likely a power of two (number of bytes). You could as well allocate a chunk of memory, sized as you see fit. For a good measure, I'd either try to ask the OS (or libc) for the allocation to be page-aligned, or if this is not possible, I'd allocate 2^N + 1 pages, and find the boundary inside the allocation. Memory mapping from kernel to user space (VM) is definitely granular at page boundaries, so you just need to mask some bottom number of bits in the address to make this page-aligned (12 bits for a 4 kB page?). Modulo huge pages, but I don't think these would hamper your practical outcome, even if used by the kernel's memory management.

Next, access the allocated buffer by an algorithm that only ever touches the odd or even strides in your expected interleaving scheme.

You could probably try to measure if it works by timing some large transfers. Large enough to trash the cache. Try a transfer that should interleave, and then a transfer that should only hit one RAM channel.

If you do in fact need to have 4kB chunks allocated continuous in a DRAM channel, your only practical chance probably is to derail interleaving on purpose, either by populating just one RAM channel, or by using two (four?) DIMM modules with unequal sizes.

Comment: It seems that in the case of unequal `DIMM`s, interleaving occurs *partially*. This can be seen in **figure 2** at **page 21** of the *`Intel` manual*, mentioned in the original quesion. In my case, the **first** `4GB` of the two `DIMM`s will use **interleaved mapping** and the **higher** `4GB` portion of the larger `DIMM` will have a **contiguous** physical address range. And it seems that the **non-interleaved** `4GB` portion contains portions of **more than** one rank.

Comment: Why would it be problematic to put `DIMM`s in the **same** channel? I think that the controller will use **another** mapping function for the **new** configuration.

Comment: The problem with the *strided allocation* is that stride **lengths** are **smaller** than `4KB`, typically in the range between `64B` and `256B`. In other words, a **contiguous** `4KB` physical address range will include consecutive `64B` ranges **alternating** between channels.

Comment: 64 Bytes... sounds like a cache line size? :-) Anyway... how do you intend to make use of 4kB allocations, with respect to power saving? Do you have an application requiring lots of memory, where you can ask the OS to give you a hefty chunk and then you'd do the housekeeping using your own custom allocator and access patterns within that chunk?

Comment: Yes. Actually, *cache line size* is a deciding factor. The application may **not** necessarily request for a `4KB` chunk. The dynamic allocator (e.g., `glibc` `malloc()`,...) **differentiates** between allocations. Some allocations, **regardless** of their size, should be allocated on a **specific** *rank*, e.g., *rank* `A`. The *dynamic allocator* informs the *OS buddy allocator* to **reserve** memory from *rank* `A`. This is where the `4KB` page size **comes into** play. Because this allocator works **at** the **page-size** granularity.

Comment: I've missed your question "Why would it be problematic to put DIMMs in the same channel?" and not sure I understand it correctly... Using just one memory channel (of the two channels technically available) obviously limits your RAM throughput. You can probably come up with some scenaria yourselfs: sequential transfers are slower, multi-threaded loads with random access can also benefit from interleaved access, the IGP needing a constant flow of data will eat away a greater percentage of the limited BW - which hurts more at high graphical resolutions / multiple displays...

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your consideration. I totally agree with you. But It seems that I have no other choice, if exclusive management of ranks is required.

Comment: Will adding a **third** DIMM in one of the slots disable the *channel-interleaving* used in the current configuration? As I said, the bottom `4GB` of the current two DIMMs **use** channel-interleaving. How can I **ensure** that?

Comment: Somebody here, https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/should-i-use-3-sticks-of-ram-or-sell-the-third.2344069/post-15490972, says that a **third** `DIMM` will probably **disable** interleaving in the first two `DIMM`s.

Comment: I guess the details of that interleaving setup are down to some unpublished algorithm in the BIOS (early POST phase, while running from "cache as RAM", where the RAM controller gets configured). Apparently with your current composition of DIMMs, the BIOS is able to match "subsets" of the RAM present in DIMMs that can be operated with identical timing, and makes use of that. It's difficult for me to suggest what combination of DIMMs would make the undocumented algorithm refrain from interleaving. I'd suggest using modules with different chips, esp. with different organization.

Comment: Or try porting Coreboot to your hardware :-) You'd have source code available.

Comment: I'm not sure, but Is the *mapping function* somewhere inside the `BIOS`? I thought that it was in the *memory controller* logic, but **sometimes** configurable by `BIOS`.

Comment: I believe that it's up to the BIOS to read the relevant timing parameters out of the SPD EEPROM (via i2c), make some sense of the set of DIMM modules thus discovered, and configure the memory controller accordingly. Such as, engage the interleaving logic, or stay with plain concatenation of the memory spaces provided by individual DIMMs, or whatever the mapping can look like. Yes the routine "address resolution function" must be in MC hardware - the translation from physical host address space to per channel and per module (per rank?) address spaces. It just gets configured during the POST.

Comment: Actually I might be kidding. Channel interleave and rank interleave are two different things. Rank interleave can happen even within a single DRAM controller channel, or in dual-channel scenaria, regardless of channel interleave status (active/inactive). Two links: Wikipedia on DRAM ranks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_rank  Coreboot source code for RAM init on the Haswell:  https://review.coreboot.org/cgit/coreboot.git/tree/src/northbridge/intel/haswell/raminit.c

Comment: Thanks! `Coreboot` is one of the things that I should investigate, someday!:D